# how to store JWT token in database

Tags: php, api, jwt, lumen, lumen-5.3

I know I'll lose the purpose if I store `jwt` token in my database but for some reason, i want to store it, how can I do that?

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @var \Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth
 */
protected $jwt;

public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwt)
{
    $this->jwt = $jwt;
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {

        if (! $token = $this->jwt->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $create_token = User::where('user_id', $login->user_id)->update(['token' => $token]);
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
        else {
        $create_token = User::where('user_id', auth()->user()->user_id)->update(['token' => $token]);
        }

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], 500);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], 500);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent' => $e->getMessage()], 500);

    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}

    public function logout(Request $request) 
{
    $this->jwt->invalidate($this->jwt->getToken());
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'User logged off successfully!'
    ], 200);
}
}
```

I tried the method above but i got error saying Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\auth()
can anyone help me??

Comment: Try `Auth::user()->id` to get user id from laravel default user's table

Comment: it does save the the token but whenever i get a new token i doesnt update the token

Comment: If you have `token` then you dont need to access `postlogin` function. you can update when the token gets updated

Comment: what if someone wants to refresh their `token` by accessing the `postlogin`, can i save the updated token? and how can i do that?

Comment: you will get newtoken in `patchRefresh` function and you can update the token to database from there

Answer (score 0):

Not advised seeing that json web tokens are time sensitive but I did write something similar but for the use of redis. Looking at your code I would advise you create row for `tokens` and add it to the  `public $hidden = ['password','token']`. When a user is created, you create and save a token to the database.